# Can a GenServer GenServer.call itself in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

This code terminates because "process attemped to call itself" on the{:handletick, ...} call handler in a GenServer:

```
defmodule PeriodicSaver do
  @moduledoc """
  Functions for periodically saving streaming data, with minute resolutions, 
  into the database
  """

  use GenServer
  use Timex


  def start_link() do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{:valuemap => %{}}, name: :periodic_saver)
  end


  def init(state) do
    IO.write "init PeriodicSaver"
    {:ok, state}
  end


  def handle_info({:inmsg, msg}, state) do
    # handles parsing of messages
    case msg do
      {:ok, %{"bstamp" => bstamp,
              "ticker" => ticker,
              "value" => value, 
              "time" => time,
              "source" => source}} -> 
        GenServer.call self(), {:handle_tick, ticker, time, value}
      _ -> 
        IO.write("ERROR")
    end
    {:noreply, state}
  end


  def handle_call({:handle_tick, ticker, time, value}, state) do
    cond do
      time > Timex.now ->
        IO.puts "Timestamp > now error"
      not Map.has_key?(state[:valuemap], ticker) ->  
        # first time this period we get this ticker
        IO.puts time
        IO.puts "helloooo"
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker], %{}
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :open], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :open], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :high], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :low], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :close], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :latest_time], time
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :next_minute], next_minute(time, 0, 1)
      state[:valuemap][ticker][:latest_time] > time -> 
        # we got an out of order time
        IO.puts "timestamp is lower than latest time for this ticker"
        IO.inspect ticker
        IO.inspect time
        IO.inspect state[:valuemap][ticker]
      state[:valuemap][ticker][:next_minute] < time -> 
        # flush to database and clear this entry from the map
        IO.write "flushing this: "
        IO.inspect state[:valuemap][ticker]
        state = pop_in(state, [:valuemap, ticker]) |> elem(1)
      true -> 
        "true found -> no conditions met"
    end
    {:reply, Nil, state}
  end


  def loop_next(x, current_time, every) do
    # finds the next minute according to the conditions
    cond do
      Timex.to_unix(x) > Timex.to_unix(current_time) -> 
        x
      true -> 
        loop_next Timex.add(x, Timex.Duration.from_minutes(every)), 
          current_time, every
    end
  end


  def next_minute(current_time, start_minute, every) do
    # next minute after which any aggregates must be saved
    Timex.today
    |> Timex.to_datetime
    |> Timex.add(Timex.Duration.from_minutes(start_minute))
    |> loop_next current_time, every
  end


end
```

As you can see I have a handle_call function with a {:handle_tick, ...} atom in it, which I am calling from within the GenServer within its handle_info({:inmsg, msg}) function. Is this not allowed? I wanted to do it this way to change the state in a consistent way. Am I supposed to just write a normal function that takes in the state and outputs a new state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenServer.call` is synchronous, thus it awaits for the result from `handle_call`, but it can't be handled, as your current `handle_info` didn't return, causing deadlock.

To avoid this problem (and especially, as you don't rely on value returned from this *call*), you can turn it to combination `send` and `handle_info`.

Consider following example:

```
def handle_info({:inmsg, msg}, state) do
# handles parsing of messages
  case msg do
  {:ok, %{"bstamp" => bstamp,
          "ticker" => ticker,
          "value" => value, 
          "time" => time,
          "source" => source}} -> 
    send(self(), {:handle_tick, ticker, time, value})
  _ -> 
    IO.write("ERROR")
 end
 {:noreply, state}
end

# ...

def handle_info({:handle_tick, ticker, time, value}, state) do
  # ...
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: "To avoid this problem you can turn it to combination send and handle_info." or `GenServer.cast` + `handle_cast`.

Comment: @Dogbert `cast` is somewhat dangerous here because if the mailbox becomes overfull, the messages will be effectively ignored.

Comment: @mudasobwa how would that be different from `send` + `handle_info`?

Comment: @Dogbert it would not, I meant both are vulnerable.

Comment: @Dogbert I agree on `handle_cast` approach would work, although I suggested `handle_info` only because this was the way used so far.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa for your comment. Agree with that, this is possible vulnerability. I suggested this approach to keep example simple, and hopefully help understanding how gen_server works

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the `GenServer` send itself a message, you could have it just call a function.

```
defmodule PeriodicSaver do
  @moduledoc """
  Functions for periodically saving streaming data, with minute resolutions, 
  into the database
  """

  use GenServer
  use Timex

  def start_link() do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{:valuemap => %{}}, name: :periodic_saver)
  end

  def init(state) do
    IO.write "init PeriodicSaver"
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:inmsg, msg}, state) do
    # handles parsing of messages
    case msg do
      {:ok, %{"bstamp" => bstamp,
              "ticker" => ticker,
              "value" => value, 
              "time" => time,
              "source" => source}} -> 
        do_tick(ticker, time, value, state)
      _ -> 
        IO.write("ERROR")
    end
    {:noreply, state}
  end


  def handle_call({:handle_tick, ticker, time, value}, state) do
    do_tick(ticker, time, value, state)
  end

  defp do_tick(ticker, time, value, state) do
    cond do
      time > Timex.now ->
        IO.puts "Timestamp > now error"
      not Map.has_key?(state[:valuemap], ticker) ->  
        # first time this period we get this ticker
        IO.puts time
        IO.puts "helloooo"
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker], %{}
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :open], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :open], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :high], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :low], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :close], value
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :latest_time], time
        state = put_in state, [:valuemap, ticker, :next_minute], next_minute(time, 0, 1)
      state[:valuemap][ticker][:latest_time] > time -> 
        # we got an out of order time
        IO.puts "timestamp is lower than latest time for this ticker"
        IO.inspect ticker
        IO.inspect time
        IO.inspect state[:valuemap][ticker]
      state[:valuemap][ticker][:next_minute] < time -> 
        # flush to database and clear this entry from the map
        IO.write "flushing this: "
        IO.inspect state[:valuemap][ticker]
        state = pop_in(state, [:valuemap, ticker]) |> elem(1)
      true -> 
        "true found -> no conditions met"
    end
    {:reply, Nil, state}
  end
end
```

Notice the creation of a new `do_tick/4` function. However, this has the potential downside of being done at the same time as the `:inmsg` is received.

Comment: “has the potential downside”—why is that? `:inmsg` will go into the mailbox until the `handle_call` has returned.

Comment: I meant that depending on the requirements of your application, you may want to do the tick handling synchronously (like my answer) or asynchronusly (like the other answer). This is specifically in regards to the `:inmsg` message.